# How to install recommended/optional perl modules from Module::Install makefiles?

Tags: perl, makefile, cpan

When you create a *Makefile.PL* with [Module::Install](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module%3a%3aInstall), you can define dependencies by using keywords like `requires`, `test_requires`, `recommends` and probably others. While installing a distribution based upon such a *Makefile.PL*, all dependencies marked as required are installed, but recommended ones are left uninstalled.

I noticed that there is a configuration option [`recommends_policy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/ANDK/CPAN-2.00/lib/CPAN.pm#Config-Variables) in newer versions of CPAN, that toggles whether to install recommended/optional packages or not. It is exactly providing the functionality I am searching for with this question.

To avoid editing my cpan configuration I would like to know, if it is possible to enable this functionality by using a command line parameter of `cpan` or a statement inside of my *Makefile.PL* that does the same, if one of the required dependencies of my distribution has recommended dependencies.

I didn't find an option in the cpan documentation, that answers my question and the documentation of [recommends in Module::Install](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Module-Install/lib/Module/Install.pod#recommends) does not provide further information.

Googling the keywords just met so many different questions and answers, that I was not able to find the needle in the haystack.

p.s. I know that I could just require the packages in my own Makefile.PL, but then I would start to manage dependencies of external projects, which is an overhead, that I'd like to avoid.

edit: I am searching for something like

```
cpan --recommends_policy=1 Module::Name
```

Comment: So you're asking us to check the `man cpan` of your version of `cpan`?

Comment: I see no reason to not edit *your* cpan configuration if you exactly want a behavior it enables. especially as the very document you linked explains in detail how you can do that while leaving the default values untouched... Then again it *also* explains how you can set individual configurations without committing them into any file (most likely setting them for this session only) so i really have no idea what your question is, seeing how you apparently did read the very document that explains your problems.

Comment: Ikegami, if I found the answer on the manpage I wouldn't ask questions. I don't know, why people on StackOverflow tend to behave like that ... thats arrogant and makes StackOverflow a disappointing place on the web. If there is the answer in a manpage, then please be helpful and explain to me, where or what I missed or didn't understand. DeVadder, since I want to give my tools to others, it would be cool, not to let them deal with additional config files, increasing complexity and increasing learning curve. I am searching for something like cpan --recommends_policy=1 Module::Name

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that the `cpan` command does. I've thought about adding a switch to set single configuration options from the command line but I don't think many people will use it.